# How to get current year in android?

Tags: java, android

I tried

```
int year = Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

but it is giving me compile time error that

> Non-static method 'get(int)' cannot be referenced from a static context.

I am calling this method from call method of observable.

```
Observable.combineLatest(ob1 ob2,
                ob3, new Func3<String, String, String, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(String a, String b, String c) {...
```

I had also seen `(new Date()).getYear();` but it is deprecated.

Comment: FYI, `Date` & `Calendar` are both legacy as of the adoption of JSR 310 years ago. Supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. For early Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* library and the *ThreeTenABP* wrapper.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yeah, you get an error because this is not a static method. First you need to create an instance of the Calendar class.
i.e.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

If your min API version is <26, you can do a shorthand as well:

```
val yearInt = Year.now().value
```

Answer (score 170):

Because you need to create an instance first.

try this

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: Correct at the time, should be java.time now. See below.

Answer (score 12):

## tl;dr

```
Year.now()
    .getValue()
```

> 2023

## java.time

The other Answers use the troublesome old date-time classes such as Calendar. These are supplanted by the java.time classes. For older versions of Android, see the ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects.

### `Year` class

Rather than pass around mere integers to represent a year, pass around objects. Namely, the [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) class.

Getting the current year requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. So it is possible for `Pacific/Auckland` to be on 2018 while `America/Montreal` is in 2017 simultaneously.

Better to pass explicitly the desired/expected zone. If omitted, you implicitly get the JVM’s current default time zone. That default can change at any moment during runtime, so it is not reliable.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
Year y = Year.now( z ) ;
```

When you do need an integer, extract the value.

```
int yearNumber = y.getValue() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: `Year` requires Android API 26 or Java 1.8.

Comment: @CoolMind Reread my Answer more carefully for solution. Look for the word “Android” mentioned two times near the bottom.

Comment: The question contains a tag `android`. So I decided to add that comment for Android programmers.

Comment: This will throw a runtime exception on Android versions under 26.

Comment: @DavidKennedy Reread the comments, the first paragraph of my Answer, and the bullets found at the end of my Answer. Look for the words “Android” and “back-port”.

Comment: True, I was just trying to make it more explicit. I was surprised the IDE didn't throw a warning or anything on my project where min SDK is 23.

Comment: @CoolMind & Big McLargeHuge, in the latest tooling for Android, much of the *java.time* functionality is now available to earlier versions of Android via "API desugaring". See links in my updates to the "About java.time" section at end of my Answer.

Comment: ZoneId.now does not work, use ZonedDateTime.

Comment: @DannyE.K.vanderKolk That typo is now fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
// get current year、month and day
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

// get current year millis
Time time = new Time(Time.TIMEZONE_UTC);
calendar.set(year, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
long year = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
time.set(year);
year = time.toMillis(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

in kotlin you can get

```
val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val currentYear = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
       LocalDate.now().year
 } else {
      calendar[Calendar.YEAR]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use

`Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)`;

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Calendar.getInstance() .get(Calendar.YEAR )` also for **Kotlin** language purposes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the code below

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

```
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // IF YOU USE HOUR IT WILL GIVE 12 HOUR USE HOUR_OF_DAY TO GET 24 HOUR FORMAT
int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int date = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // in java month starts from 0 not from 1 so for december 11+1 = 12
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

WIth Kotlin

```
LocalDateTime.now().year
```